# How to estimate disk space used by a directory excluding certain subdirectory?

Tags: unix, du

I want to estimate the amount of disk space used by a user via Apple Remote Desktop Unix command.

I've been trying the following command, running as root

```
sudo du -sh /users/
```

but I'd like to add the exclusion to ignore the size of the `/users/admin` directory.

The `du` manual shows `-I[mask]` as the way to do this, but I can't get it to work. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

```
du -sh -Iadmin /Users
```

will ignore any subdirectory "admin", e.g. /Users/admin - *on a Mac*. Please check if your *target* system supports the `-I` option (`man du`).

You might probably have to use `--exclude=admin` instead, if the target system has a GNU coreutils `du`.

Comment: Perfect thanks - I was trying many variations of -I=admin but as you say, I didn't need the '=' :)